Which novels by Francis Hardinge take place in the same setting?
The author Francis Hardinge has several books that take place in constructed worlds—obviously, Twilight Robbery is a sequel to Fly By Night, but Gullstruck Island, A Face Like Glass, Deeplight and Unraveller all take place in superficially separate settings.
However, all of these books take place in geographically limited locations, usually a single country at most, with the existence of a larger world indicated but not elaborated upon in all of them, and the magic in each one, if any, is usually implied to be rather local (e.g. the Wilds and their fae inhabitants are only in Raddith, the Undersea is only present near the Myriad, and so forth). This suggests the possibility that some of these books share a larger world.
Which books by Francis Hardinge, if any, take place in the same continuity?
